# 301 redirection for wildcard urls in webconfig rules

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, iis, http-status-code-301

I tried lots... I don't get the domain to redirect

301 redirection to wildcard URLs

I have https://www.example.com/blog wild card - https://blog.example.com/

I need to redirect the domain this **https://www.example.com/blog to this one  https://blog.example.com/**

**/blog to https://blog.example.com/**

> ```
>   <rule name="Redirect blog" stopProcessing="true">
>     <match url=".*" />
>     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
>       <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="/blog$" />
>     </conditions>
>     <action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.example.com/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
>   </rule>
> ```

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 The common mistakes are caused by misunderstanding of various URL rewriting concepts. In your case, you got `HTTP_HOST` wrong.

Comment: I also use the {url} but not works

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution

```
    <rule name="Blog Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www\.)?example.com$" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/blog$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.example.com" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use {PATH_INFO} instead of {HTTP_HOST}

```
 <rule name="Redirect blog" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
      <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="/blog$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.example.com/" redirectType="Permanent"/>
  </rule>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match those ending in blog, then you can try the below rule:

```
  <rule name="Redirect blog" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^blog(/)?(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.example.com/{R:2}" />
            </rule>
```

If you want to match all, then you can try this rule:

```
 <rule name="Redirect blog" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^blog(/)?(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://blog.example.com/" />
            </rule>
```